# Gatsby error while compiling tailwindcss snippets

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, tailwind-css

I have this issue concerning gatsby whenever compiling some tailwindcss snippets something like : `w-1/4 lg:bottom-auto ...` it does accept `w-full` and some other basic implementations . This is the error when I compile :

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (39:13)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-postcss/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export var fontThin = "layout-module--font-thin--AYgoG";
| export var uppercase = "layout-module--uppercase--4I4v2";
> export var lg:bottomAuto = "layout-module--lg:bottom-auto--q5Wel";
| export var lg:translateX0 = "layout-module--lg:translate-x-0--6WAuC";
| export default ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___;

File: src\styles\layout.module.css:39:13

failed Re-building development bundle - 1.231s
ERROR in ./src/styles/layout.module.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (39:13)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-postcss/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export var fontThin = "layout-module--font-thin--AYgoG";
| export var uppercase = "layout-module--uppercase--4I4v2";
> export var lg:bottomAuto = "layout-module--lg:bottom-auto--q5Wel";
| export var lg:translateX0 = "layout-module--lg:translate-x-0--6WAuC";
| export default ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___;
    at handleParseError
 @ ./src/components/Layout.js 8:0-37
 @ ./src/pages/login.js 9:0-42
 @ ./.cache/_this_is_virtual_fs_path_/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
 @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 30:87-34:1 33:29-42 36:27-40 30:0-34:2

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
develop compiled with 2 errors
success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.598s - 0/2 3.35/s
```